Problem with windows in Ubuntu 24.04
I have a problem with graphic effects in the OS. After a "clean" installation of Nvidia graphics drivers, I have two problems...

When working in different apps, when I need to click something on the edge of the window (and sometimes not only on the edge), I am transferred to the window of another app, it is very annoying!
There is no menu to control resize of the window when hovering over the edge of the window, you have to use the context menu for that...

I did different configurations but none solved the problem. I switched between X11 and Wayland, tried to install different versions of the Nvidia driver, nothing helped.
Note. If you remove the graphics driver, the problems disappear.
OC                        Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Architecture:             x86_64
Vendor:                   Asus
Model:                    Vivobook K6602ZC
CPU:                      12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-12650H
GPU:                      Nvidia 3050 laptop
Windows system:           X11
Nvidia drivers:           535

How to fix this issue?

I don't see any questions asked here. Please don't make us guess.

Can you install a different graphics driver in additional software tab in Software Sources?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

How can I explain the visual bug? I explained as best I could. There are 2 open windows of different apps, you are working in application number one and you need to press something button to the edge of the window, the system switches you to window of app number two...

@ArchismanPanigrahi Yes, added it to the main question. I can provide a video if it helps to identify the problem

Bugs are off topic here.

@user68186 I can't identify the problem to understand where to write..

You might get better help if you limit your questions to one item. e.g. Ubuntu 24.04 desktop login with Wayland, when resizing the gnome-terminal the horizontal/vertical size in a bubble in the center of the terminal does not display like it does under xorg. Someone might suggest a configuration solution, but that problem seems like a bug to me, which should be reported on the launchpad site (use ubuntu-bug to report it).
